# spring integration aws s3 delete local file

Tags: spring-integration

I am using spring integration to read file from s3 however this works but  my  local directory is getting full I want to delete files from local directory after files are processed from s3?

```
    <bean id="credentials" class="org.springframework.integration.aws.core.BasicAWSCredentials">
        <property name="accessKey" value="${accessKey}"/>
        <property name="secretKey" value="${secretKey}"/>
    </bean>



    <bean id="clientConfiguration" class="com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration">
        <property name="proxyHost" value="${proxyHost}"/>
        <property name="proxyPort" value="${proxyPort}"/>
    <property name="preemptiveBasicProxyAuth" value="false"/> 
    </bean>

    <bean id="s3Operations" class="org.springframework.integration.aws.s3.core.CustomC1AmazonS3Operations">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="credentials"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" ref="clientConfiguration"/>
        <property name="awsEndpoint" value="s3.amazonaws.com"/>
        <property name="temporaryDirectory" value="${temporaryDirectory}"/>
        <property name="awsSecurityKey"  value="${awsSecurityKey}"/>
    </bean>



    <!-- aws-endpoint="https://s3.amazonaws.com"  -->
    <int-aws:s3-inbound-channel-adapter aws-endpoint="s3.amazonaws.com"
                                        bucket="${bucket}"
                                        s3-operations="s3Operations"
                                        credentials-ref="credentials"
                                        file-name-wildcard="${fileNameWildcard}"
                                        remote-directory="${remoteDirectory}"
                                        channel="splitChannel"
                                        local-directory="${localDirectory}"
                                        accept-sub-folders="false"
                                        delete-source-files="true"
                                        archive-bucket="${archiveBucket}"
                                        archive-directory="${archiveDirectory}">
    </int-aws:s3-inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are looking for `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`.

Please, find [Retry and More](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/retry-and-more). There is something like `<property name="onSuccessExpression" value="payload.delete()" />` in the `expression-advice-context.xml` config to take care about the local file after the proper finish of the process.

Comment: thanks Artem .But where to plugin the ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice in my applicationcontext shown above for int-aws:s3-inbound-channel-adapter

Comment: On some `<service-activator>` downstream. I'm sure you have something after that `splitChannel`.