# error while invoking service activator

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am trying to invoke a advice from a service activator I am getting below exception

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
       xmlns:int-aws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/aws"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/aws http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/aws/spring-integration-aws-1.0.xsd">

    <int:poller fixed-delay="${fixedDelay}" default="true"/>

    <bean id="credentials" class="org.springframework.integration.aws.core.BasicAWSCredentials">
        <property name="accessKey" value="${accessKey}"/>
        <property name="secretKey" value="${secretKey}"/>
    </bean>


    <!-- aws-endpoint="https://s3.amazonaws.com"  proxyHost="proxy.kdc.capitalone.com" proxyPort="8099"-->
    <bean id="clientConfiguration" class="com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration">
        <property name="proxyHost" value="${proxyHost}"/>
        <property name="proxyPort" value="${proxyPort}"/>
    <property name="preemptiveBasicProxyAuth" value="false"/> 
    </bean>

    <bean id="s3Operations" class="org.springframework.integration.aws.s3.core.CustomC1AmazonS3Operations">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="credentials"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" ref="clientConfiguration"/>
        <property name="awsEndpoint" value="s3.amazonaws.com"/>
        <property name="temporaryDirectory" value="${temporaryDirectory}"/>
        <property name="awsSecurityKey"  value="${awsSecurityKey}"/>
    </bean>



    <!-- aws-endpoint="https://s3.amazonaws.com"  -->
    <int-aws:s3-inbound-channel-adapter aws-endpoint="s3.amazonaws.com"
                                        bucket="${bucket}"
                                        s3-operations="s3Operations"
                                        credentials-ref="credentials"
                                        file-name-wildcard="${fileNameWildcard}"
                                        remote-directory="${remoteDirectory}"
                                        channel="splitChannel"
                                        local-directory="${localDirectory}"
                                        accept-sub-folders="false"
                                        delete-source-files="true"
                                        archive-bucket="${archiveBucket}"
                                        archive-directory="${archiveDirectory}">
    </int-aws:s3-inbound-channel-adapter>

    <int:service-activator ref="expressionAdvice"  input-channel="splitChannel"  requires-reply="false"/>

    <bean id="expressionAdvice" class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">
        <property name="onSuccessExpression" value="payload.delete()" />

    </bean>

    <int:splitter input-channel="splitChannel" output-channel="output"
                  expression="T(org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils).lineIterator(payload)">
    <int:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">
            <property name="onSuccessExpression" value="payload.delete()"/>
        </bean>
    </int:request-handler-advice-chain>
    </int:splitter>

    <int:channel id="output"/>


</beans>
```

---

```
2015-12-22T13:42:26-0600 1.2.1.RELEASE WARN DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactoryBean#0' while setting bean property 'handler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactoryBean#0': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Found ambiguous parameter type [interface org.springframework.expression.Expression] for method match: [public final void org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationObjectSupport.afterPropertiesSet(), public void org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationObjectSupport.setChannelResolver(org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolver), public void org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice.setExpressionOnFailure(org.springframework.expression.Expression), public void org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice.setTrapException(boolean), public void org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice.setFailureChannel(org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel), public final void org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationObjectSupport.setBeanFactory(org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory), public void org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationObjectSupport.setApplicationContext(org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext) throws org.springframework.beans.BeansException, public final java.lang.Object org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.invoke(org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInvocation) throws java.lang.Throwable, public void org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationObjectSupport.setComponentName(java.lang.String), public void org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationObjectSupport.setMessageBuilderFactory(org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilderFactory)]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that this design is a bit strange. The `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` is for the `<request-handler-advice-chain>` as a sub-elemen of `<service-activator>`:

```
<file:outbound-channel-adapter channel="appendToFileChannel"
                               filename-generator-expression="headers.file_name"
                               mode="APPEND"
                               directory="/foo">
    <file:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">
            <property name="onSuccessExpression" value="payload.delete()"/>
        </bean>
    </file:request-handler-advice-chain>
</file:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

Please, consult, [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#message-handler-advice-chain) for more information.

Comment: I was trying this for my previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34420049/spring-integration-aws-s3-delete-local-file/34421032#34421032

Comment: Right, that's why I sent you there to the sample about files to see how to use `<request-handler-advice-chain>`. Plus see the documentation mentioned here.

Comment: Yes my  application xml looks something like this.I updated .The downstream to splitchannel is my line splitter still same exception

Comment: Yes, you good there on the `<splitter>`. You don't need `<int:service-activator>` there at all.